# Does simplemodal mess up ASP.NET AJAXified controls?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, simplemodal

Does simplemodal mess up ASP.NET AJAXified controls? It would appear that after showing the modal, using something that uses AJAX, closing the modal and re-opening it, the AJAXified controls no longer work.

Is this because of simplemodal or coincidental? Are there workarounds for this behavior if it is due to simple modal? I would rather not use jquery UI, because the library is huge and all I really want is this modal functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used ASP.NET AJAXified controls but i used Simplemodal quite a lot. Simplemodal clone html elements when opens. So the problem you described could happend because of that. As a workaround try to set `persist:true` in that case simplemodal does not clone the elements.

```
$("#simplemodal-popup").modal({ persist: true });
```

http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

> persist [Boolean:false] Persist the data across modal calls? Only used
>   for existing DOM elements. If true, the data will be maintained across
>   modal calls, if false, the data will be reverted to its original
>   state.